# Can I use form field data before validation?

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

This works (to my surprise), but I'm not sure if it is correct:

```
@app.route('/example', methods=['POST']) # no GET, only POST
def example():
    form = MyForm()
    cmd = mk_cmd('CMD_12', form.duration.data)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # some preparation          
        exec_cmd(cmd)
    else:
        # error handling
    return flask.redirect(...)
```

Why am I asking? I'd like to refactor several very similar functions to just few lines (DRY principle) :

```
def example():
    form = MyForm()
    cmd = mk_cmd('CMD_12', form.duration.data)
    return check_and_exec(form, cmd)
```

and in order to do that I need to build the command from form data before validation. The command will be thrown away if the validation fails.